# Two way one to many relationship

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I have two domain classes one is Game:

```
class Game {
   String name
   String description
   Double price
   static hasMany = [reviews: Review]
}
```

and the other one is Review:

```
class Review {
   String reviewText
   Date reviewDate
   static belongsTo = [game: Game]
}
```

Both are stripped down versions. I have two objects

```
r1 = new Review([reviewText: "A game review", reviewDate: new Date()])
g = new Game([name:"Angry Birds", description:"Parabolic physics like game", 20.00])
r1.game=g
r1.save()
```

After above call is this statement legal?

```
g.reviews
```

Will it return a list of all reviews associated with Game? Actually I have an old Grails code which is fetching list of reviews by g.reviews like calls and on Grails 2.4.4, I am getting a null. Was it legal in older versions of Grails? What is the recommended way to fetch reviews associated with a particular game?

Comment: After I performed g.delete(), it only removed the game from the database while the reviews were intact. As per grails documentation, it was supposed to cascade delete operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

save with `flush:true` if you want to immediately access the db.

```
r1.save(flush:true)
```

then you can say:

```
g.reviews
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Somehow this too is not working for me. Here is (http://pastebin.com/dV5ANS4f) my grails shell output.

Comment: Whether I use flush:true or not, I can only see my changes after a restart. My reviews table is updated in my DB but g.reviews still returns null. Once I exit grails shell and restart it, g.reviews shows the reviews I added in previous session.It is quite strange. Is it because of Hibernate's behavior that it performs DB operation in one go when it has enough entries? How can I alter this behavior?

Comment: Regarding my comment about cascade delete, it works only if I restart the application. g.delete() deletes the game as well as related reviews from DB record (confirmed this by viewing tables in my postgres) but g.name still returns the name instead of null and g.reviews returns the reviews even though it was deleted from DB. Hibernate is surely pulling this from caches and if I restart app, I get what I expect. But this is a painful activity to restart app every time I update record.

Comment: After disabling second level cache cache.use_second_level_cache = false, I can see my changes as I expect.

Comment: Nope. Ignore my last comment. I can't get updates even after disabling second level cache.